# Meaning of Qu'en in English

Tags: sens, linguistique

Quel est le sens de  "**Qu'en**", et quand puis-je l'utiliser ?

Please note that I am a very beginner in French.

Comment: Pouvez-vous donner des exemples d'utilisation ?

Comment: “Qu'en” is simply “que + en”, the difficulty is the word “en”, which has many slightly different uses, are you familiar with it?

Comment: This sequence of two words can be used in so many contexts that asking for a translation is meaningless. Give us the full sentence you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Gilles I was having a french exam to determine my level ( although I am a beginner), one of the quetions was to fill in the blank by  " Quand , Quant, Qu'en". I am some how familiar with **Quand**  and  **Quant**, but the difficulty for me was with **Qu'en**. I googled  trying to understand how to use it, but it seems for me very complicated.

Comment: @Relaxed I am not very familiar with **en**, would  you please give me some indications and usages?

Comment: @Nizar Can't you provide the sentences that were in the exam ? As Gilles said, it can be used in so many contexts... "Je ne suis doué qu'en maths", "Il sait qu'en reculant, il n'avancera pas"...

Comment: @Nizar Very briefly, **en** is either a [preposition](http://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/en-preposition/) meaning _in_, _to_, _into_, or a [pronoun](http://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/en-adverbial-pronoun/) with the general meaning _of/from/about it/them_. Here's an example of each, where **qu'en** is not only possible but also required: On va plus vite en métro qu'en voiture. (It's faster to go by subway than by car.) Qu'en pensez-vous ? (What do you think about it?)

Comment: **en** as a pronoun refers to the noun after **de / de la / du** (the quantifier that means **some**, **many**, etc. Don't confuse with **de** meaning **from** ("Je viens **de** loin"), or with possession ("Le père **de** mon ami)).
"Veux-tu lui donner **du pain**?" -> "Veux-tu lui **en** donner?" (you can find **m'en** is a shortcut for **me en**). Translation ("Can you give him some bread? Can you give him some?"
"Que penses-tu de **mon idée**?" -> "Qu'**en** penses-tu?" (What do you think of my idea? What do you think of it?)